# Loki - running on a Chromebook using crouton

Tags: release-loki, google-chrome, dependencies, chromebook

Yesterday I installed Loki on a an HP 14 Chromebook. Everything is perfect except ...

I can't get Chrome to install in the Elementary environment. I have downloaded the install file from Google and installed the **GDebi Package Installer**. When I try to run the Chrome install package with either the **GDebi installer** or **Ubuntu Software Center**, I get the following error:

`Dependency is not satisfiable: libfontconfig1 (>=2.9.0)`

I ran an update for this file with the following command:
`sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1`

The command results in the following:

```
libfontconfig1 is already the newest version. 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
(precise)asc@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install libfontconfig 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
libfontconfig1 is already the newest version. 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

After running this command, the problem persists. The command results indicate that all is as it should be, but it still doesn't work. Can't figure out what to do next.

I have installed Chromium so am getting along, but would really like to have Chrome installed. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you have downloaded the 64 bit google chrome?

Comment: Definitely have 64-bit version. It's the only option that the download page gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to install from a terminal with

```
 sudo dpkg --install ~/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
 sudo apt-get install -f
```

so that you get more verbose error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, *lemonslice*! Excellent suggestion.

It occurs to me (DUH!) that I am not running the latest version of Ubuntu. The latest that crouton supported was ... I think ... Trusty. I'm thinking that this is perhaps the root of the issue?

### I'm just digging into the nuts and bolts of Linux so that escaped me. Looks like I have three dependency issues:

```
google-chrome-stable depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0); however:
Version of libfontconfig1 on system is 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.2.
google-chrome-stable depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.8.0); however:
Version of libstdc++6 on system is 4.6.3-1ubuntu5.
google-chrome-stable depends on lsb-base (>= 4.1); however:
Version of lsb-base on system is 4.0-0ubuntu20.3.
```

I ran **sudo apt-get upgrade** on all of those, but it didn't result in anything.

### I am assuming that I need to somehow force an upgrade of those three files but have no idea how (or if that's even the right course).

*Full error message here:*

```
(precise)asc@localhost:~$ sudo dpkg --install ~/Downloads/installs/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 115476 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace google-chrome-stable 55.0.2883.87-1 (using .../google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement google-chrome-stable ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
google-chrome-stable depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0); however:
Version of libfontconfig1 on system is 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.2.
google-chrome-stable depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.8.0); however:
Version of libstdc++6 on system is 4.6.3-1ubuntu5.
google-chrome-stable depends on lsb-base (>= 4.1); however:
Version of lsb-base on system is 4.0-0ubuntu20.3.
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

### google-chrome-stable

FWIW, apt-get check returns this:

```
google-chrome-stable : 
Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) but 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.2 is installed
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.8.0) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
Depends: lsb-base (>= 4.1) but 4.0-0ubuntu20.3 is installed
```

Comment: FWIW, apt-get check returns this:

    google-chrome-stable : 
    / Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) but 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.2 is installed
    / Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.8.0) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
    / Depends: lsb-base (>= 4.1) but 4.0-0ubuntu20.3 is installed